# How to access SVG elements using protractor

Tags: xpath, svg, kendo-ui, protractor, karma-jasmine

I am using kendo donut chart, the chart loads fine in the UX/UI with data being displayed. Now I am writing a functional test using protractor/jasmine and I need to access the values of the chart.

Normally element(by.xpath) or element(by.css) works for HTML controls. but since kendo donut makes use of SVG, element(by.xpath) or element(by.css) does not work.

How can I access the SVG elements in protractor/jasmine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made use of element(by.binding('vm.results')) on the div where I have the kendo-chart

```
<div kendo-chart="kchart" data-k-options="vm.options" k-data-source="vm.results" data-role="chart" class="k-chart" style="position: relative;"></div>
```

I accessed the kendo donut chart like so:

```
element(by.binding('vm.results')).getText();
```

with this I am able to get the legend details I needed